# how to use raw react app in vs for mac

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

I'd like to integrate/use an aspnet core 2 mvc app with react built using the react CLI "create-react-app".
I'd prefer to avoid all the boilerplate provide by SPA template.
Could you please me help to figure out all the steps required to integrate for. ex. gulp to code against the app created with the CLI in VS editor and see the result when I launch the website from VS and see the change while the website is running?